# Regular expression case sensitive

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, case-sensitive

im trying to get this regular expression to work but im having problems with javascript exception because of the case sensitive.

I have my regular expression in my model and some words should not be able to write such as "and" "or" "ok" "not. but if i write Andy it should work

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?!\b(?:AND|O[RK]|NOT|FALSE|TRUE)\b)[\wåäöÅÄÖ\._])*$\i", ErrorMessageResourceName
```

i can't use the regularoption ( Regex.ignoreCase) so im trying to use \i but getting javascript error.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are using a backslash to use case insensitive flag but you need to use a forward slash like this:

```
var re = /^(?:(?!\b(?:AND|O[RK]|NOT|FALSE|TRUE)\b)[\wåäöÅÄÖ._])*$/i;
                                                         HERE----^
```

Comment: @Cosy check this link http://regex101.com/r/sY7oH6/3. Take a look at Code Generator section to copy the javascript code

Comment: @Cosy btw, if you want you can edit your question and add some sample inputs and your desired output to point what are valid and invalid matches and I'd be able to provide another regex or help you with the existing one

Comment: i've tried that side but not getting the case sensitive :( ... Its driving me crazy :( . If i write AND it works but if i write And it doesn't work. I need to find where to put the i . I also trying on debuggex https://www.debuggex.com/#cheatsheet ... dead end too

Comment: @Cosy your regex work fine http://debuggex.com/i/ZlGGjFR7bWJ3d6D-.png. If you put AND or and it won't match if you use andy it will. Your regex match words that aren't AND or OR or OK or NOT... etc

Comment: Its not kicking in when i write and in lower case so i need it to be case insensitive

Comment: @Cosy you can check in this link http://regex101.com/r/sY7oH6/4 that everything is working.